# How can non-associative operators like "<" be specified in ANTLR4 grammars?

Tags: antlr4

In a rule `expr : expr '<' expr | ...;`
the ANTLR parser will accept expressions like `1 < 2 < 3` (and construct left-associative trees corrsponding to brackets `(1 < 2) < 3`.

You can tell ANTLR to treat operators as right associative, e.g.

```
expr : expr '<'<assoc=right> expr | ...;
```

to yield parse trees `1 < (2 < 3)`.

However, in many languages, relational operators are *non-associative*, i.e., an expression `1 < 2 < 3` is *forbidden*.
This can be specified in YACC and its derivates.

Can it also be specified in ANTLR? 
E.g., as `expr : expr '<'<assoc=no> expr | ...;`

I was unable to find something in the ANTLR4-book so far.

Comment: IANAGuru, but it may be that you can't (sanely) enforce it except by either (A) adding predicates/action-code to the grammar or (B) doing a post-parse validation step.

Comment: Hmm, still no answer? Well, what would you do anyway if someone **did** put A<B<C? You make it sound like an unrecoverable flaw in the input. I'd post-process the parse-tree (with a listener) and generate an error whenever directly nested < operations are found.

Answer (score 1):

How about the following approach. Basically the "result" of `a < b` has a type not compatible for another application of operator `<` or `>`:

```
expression
    :   boolExpression
    |   nonBoolExpression
    ;

boolExpression
    :   nonBoolExpression '<' nonBoolExpression
    |   nonBoolExpression '>' nonBoolExpression
    |   ...
    ;

nonBoolExpression
    :   expression '*' expression
    |   expression '+' expression
    |   ...
    ;
```

Although personally I'd go with [Darien](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19023046/how-can-non-associative-operators-like-be-specified-in-antlr4-grammars#comment28513077_19023046)  and rather detect the error after parsing.